# What is the difference between API Client & Security Profile

Tags: ordercloud

According to the official [documentation](https://ordercloud.io/learn/getting-started/establishing-api-access):

> API Clients - API clients are access points to your marketplace data.
> These access points have properties that control what parties can use
> it, how they can gain access, and for how long that access remains
> valid.

But isn't a `Security Profile` also used to control access.
For example, I would create two profiles - seller & buyer for respective users.
What is the need for API client here and should we have it always?

Please help me understand this with any example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think about the two like this: ***[Security Profiles](https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/security-profiles) are to users, as [API Clients](https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/api-clients) are to applications.***

Security Profiles are groups of roles that are assigned to users (at varying levels of assignment, be it at the Buyer level, User Group level, or even down to specific users). These groups of roles (or Security Profiles) define what level of data access specific users have.

API Clients are partitioned to grant access to your marketplace's data to specific applications. You could think of them like "API Keys". It is encouraged that you use API Clients liberally in order to have granular control.  For instance, if you have a buyer application, an admin application, a middleware API, and a nightly webjob, it would be encouraged that you have 4 different API Clients, one for each of those applications.

Then, when your users are authenticating into one of your applications, you include the API Client for that specific application in the [authentication request to OrderCloud](https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/authentication). It is important to keep in mind that if your API Client has a Client Secret defined, it must be sent along with any authentication request grant type.  API ClientIDs are not sensitive, however if you have a Client Secret defined, this is sensitive and should be protected and never publicly exposed.

A good reason for using API Clients liberally would be in the unfortunate case that your Client Secret was exposed, you could deactivate the specific API Client for this application without affecting many other applications, while you swap out with a new API Client.

**To summarize**: Security Profiles are used to grant specific data access to to users, and API Clients are used to grant specific data access to your applications.  Both are required for a user to successfully authenticate to OrderCloud and begin making requests.

Answer (score 1):

Security profiles are groups of roles (permissions), each of which grant users access to specific API endpoints and functionality.
More information about **security profiles** can be found here:
https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/security-profiles

OrderCloud uses the term API Clients to identify various access points to your marketplace's data. These access points have properties that control what parties can use it, how they can gain access, and for how long that access remains valid.
More information about **API Clients** can be found here:
https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/api-clients